# USB host shield help

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, shields

[image]
Hello, I apologise for being such a noob but can someone help with this.
I am having trouble working with this. When I insert the arduino's pins into my new usb host shield , there is no indication light and when I plugged my Xbox receiver into the shield it does not turn on as it would with my desktop. Any thoughts? Please post below

Comment: We need more information. See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask E.g. What have you tried? Do other devices work? Can your program access the shield at all? What makes you think it should light up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the clear photo is helpful because it shows the USB host board has the [following problem](https://esp8266-notes.blogspot.com/2017/08/defective-arduino-usb-host-shield-boards.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, google wasn't producing many results. I guess budget-chinese parts are a bit dodgy.

Comment: Please include the relevant information in your answer. Once the link breaks, there will be nothing in your post to give readers even a slightest hint about the problem.